# How to escape Apostrophe characters used in SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a sql query in Mysql query browser

**select * from example where name like 'canniba'ls' ;**

its returning sql syntax error, check the manual.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [QUOTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) function.

Comment: Wouldn't the OP already need to know how to escape apostrophes in order to construct the string argument to QUOTE()?  Also, how do you propose the OP use this?  `'canniba\'ls' <> QUOTE('canniba\'ls')`, after all.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from example where name like 'canniba''ls';
```

would do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from example where name like 'canniba\'ls' ;
```

would do it for the command line. When using it from an app, make sure you use a sane escaping function.

Answer (score 0):

The escape character is a backslash `\`, so your query would be:

```
select * from example where name like 'canniba\'ls';
```

If your query parameters are not hardcoded and come from a variable, be sure to parameterise your query to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.